# rpm is freezing in the same moment

Tags: centos, rpm

I'm trying to install an rpm package:

```
rpm -i rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

And got this via strace:

http://pastebin.com/zP45epkd

I'm on CentOS 5.7 64-bit:

```
2.6.18-274.18.1.el5 #1 SMP 
Thu Feb 9 12:45:44 EST 2012 
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: is it just this one rpm, or all ? As the rpmforge rpm just adds a little bit to yum.repos.d you could do it manually easy enough.

Comment: It happens on all rpm's. It's just an example.

Comment: /proc/mounts seems to be messed up. Can you post it entirely?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Rm2k2BJR - it looks strange to me - how can I fix this ?

Comment: I found this in /etc/rc.local which is incorrect - ln -s /dev/md2 /dev/root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to remove bind and switch to tinydns. No more issues !